# android: proguard obfuscating imported jars

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I've made a IM client that uses the asmack .jar library to communicate with google IM service server.

Now I am trying to export my application from eclipse and use the proguard tool to obfuscate my classes.
The problem is that after exporting the project and running it, I can't log on to google because I get errors from the asmack lib...
one of the errors: `01-21 09:52:19.602: WARN/System.err(24297): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values`
I also get NoSuchClassException and some names of packages from asmack.

What settings do I have to make to get this work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved... I had to put all the classes noticed in the error in the -keep public class property of progurad